# Why does probability work like this?

Tags: probability, statistics

I do not quite understand how the probability, when I know $C$ happened, that $A$ occured is $\frac{P(A∩C)}{P(A∩C)+P(B∩C)}$. I am not sure how to write those probabilities, but I can show you what I mean with a numbers example. Here is the tree diagram:

[image: tree diagram]

$C$ and $D$ are the same events each time, but they have different probabilities. Let me make up an example:

*Please correct me if I am using syntax wrong, I am a learner and this is why I add comments to each statement.*

$P(A)=.3$, the probability that $A$ occurs

$P(B)=.7$, respectively that $B$ occurs

For $A$:

$P_A(C)=.4$

$P_A(D) =.6$

I think that $P_A(...)$ means "when $A$ happened probability of (...)"

For $B$:

$P_B(C)=.8$

$P_B(D) =.2$

At the end:

$$
P(A∩C) = (.3)(.4) = .12
$$
$$
P(A∩D) = (.3)(. 6) = .18
$$
$$
P(B∩C) = (.7)(.8) = .56
$$
$$
P(B∩D) = (.7)(.2) = .14
$$
With this numbers example the probability that, when $C$ happened, that $A$ happened would be $\frac{.12}{.12+.56}$.

I would like to understand why this works and also thoughts on notation. The exercise where I found myself wondering about this uses this notation: $P(A|C)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the equation

$$
P(A \cap C)= P(C)P(A|C)\,.
$$

In order for $A$ and $C$ to happen simultaneously, $C$ must happen (which takes place with probability $P(C)$) and $A$ must also happen (which takes place with probability $P(A|C)$, since we know that $C$ has already happened).

We can rearrange this into the following.
$$
P(A|C)=\frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}
$$

You get your fraction by observing that $P(C)=P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)$.  Why is this true?  Well, you know that either $A$ happens or $B$ happens (but not both).  So, in order for $C$ to happen, either $A$ and $C$ must happen together, or $B$ and $C$ must happen together.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I was able to follow it very nicely. What really bugs me is the fact that I cannot explain to myself how the probability of $C$ happening inthe $A$ tree is itself devided by the sum of both probabilities of $C$ happening, i.e. in the $A$ tree and in the $B$ tree. I understand how we can derive it from what you said, but I cannot comprehend the division without looking at your first equation. Can you provide me with some mental aid here?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot OK, think of it this way.  If you know that $C$ happened, then you are restricting to the two branches that end with $C$.  So if we are given that $C$ happened, then those two branches are now our 'world'.  Because we want probabilities to go from $0$ to $1$ in our world, we divide by the probability of ending up in one of those two branches.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I think that I will just accept the rules and not think about it anymore. I hope that it will occur to me somewhen.

Answer (score 1):

Your $P_A(C)$ is typically denoted $P(C \mid A)$. The end of your post recovers the mathematical definition of this quantity: $P(A \cap C) = P(A) \cdot P(C \mid A)$.

Comment: Does this mean that $P(A \mid B)$ reads as "probability of $B$ when $A$ occured?".

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot The other way around: "probability of $A$ when $B$ occurred." The usual phrasing is "probability of $B$ *given that* $A$ occurred."

Comment: I think that this is what I meant. I guess that I was a bit sluggish with my phrasing. Thanks, I will try to incorporate this in the future. To me all three of the statements listed in our conversation mean the same, I think that I am still misunderstanding something, somehow. The phrasing of the solution to the exercise I mentioned was "Probability of event $A$ happening considering that we know that event $C$ happened.". Which of all the statements are applicable to that?

Comment: Ah I think that I got it now. Thanks to [this article](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/condprob.htm), I think that you made a typo when writing "$B$ given that $A$" and wanted to write it the other way around. Thank you.